# XML documentation for doc generators bloats files

Tags: c#, xml, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm using Doxygen to generate documentation based on the XML commenting on my source files. The problem I have though is the amount of bloat in the file. There's more comments than there are actual lines of code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer allows for starting a timer that will execute a callback at a given interval.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The timer may fire:
///  - infinitely at the given interval
///  - fire once
///  - fire _n_ number of times.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer will stop its self when it is disposed of.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Timer requires you to provide it an instance that will have an operation performed against it.
/// The callback will be given the generic instance at each interval fired.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// In the following example, the timer is given an instance of an IPlayer. 
/// It starts the timer off with a 30 second delay before firing the callback for the first time.
/// It tells the timer to fire every 60 seconds with 0 as the number of times to fire. When 0 is provided, it will run infinitely.
/// Lastly, it is given a callback, which will save the player every 60 seconds.
/// @code
/// var timer = new EngineTimer<IPlayer>(new DefaultPlayer());
/// timer.StartAsync(30000, 6000, 0, (player, timer) => player.Save());
/// @endcode
/// </para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type that will be provided when the timer callback is invoked.</typeparam>
public sealed class EngineTimer<T> : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The timer task
    /// </summary>
    private Task timerTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// How many times we have fired the timer thus far.
    /// </summary>
    private long fireCount = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EngineTimer{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The state.</param>
    public EngineTimer(T state)
    {
        this.StateData = state;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object that was provided to the timer when it was instanced.
    /// This object will be provided to the callback at each interval when fired.
    /// </summary>
    public T StateData { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the engine timer is currently running.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>
    /// Starts the timer, firing a synchronous callback at each interval specified until `numberOfFires` has been reached.
    /// If `numberOfFires` is 0, then the callback will be called indefinitely until the timer is manually stopped.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// The following example shows how to start a timer, providing it a callback.
    /// </para>
    /// @code
    /// var timer = new EngineTimer<IPlayer>(new DefaultPlayer());
    /// double startDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds;
    /// double interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
    /// int numberOfFires = 0;
    /// 
    /// timer.Start(
    ///     startDelay, 
    ///     interval, 
    ///     numberOfFires, 
    ///     (player, timer) => player.Save());
    /// @endcode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">
    /// <para>
    /// The `startDelay` is used to specify how much time must pass before the timer can invoke the callback for the first time.
    /// If 0 is provided, then the callback will be invoked immediately upon starting the timer.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// The `startDelay` is measured in milliseconds.
    /// </para>
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void Start(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Action<T, EngineTimer<T>> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                (task, state) => RunTimer(task, (Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the specified start delay.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">The start delay in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void StartAsync(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                async (task, state) => await RunTimerAsync(task, (Tuple<Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer for this instance.
    /// Stopping the timer will not dispose of the EngineTimer, allowing you to restart the timer if you need to.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.Cancel();
        } 
        this.IsRunning = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer and releases the unmanaged resources used by the <see cref="T:System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource" /> class and optionally releases the managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.IsRunning = false;
            this.Cancel();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private async Task RunTimer(Task task, Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task RunTimerAsync(Task task, Tuple<Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            await state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformTimerCancellationCheck(double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        // If we have reached our fire count, stop. If set to 0 then we fire until manually stopped.
        if (numberOfFires > 0 && this.fireCount >= numberOfFires)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval), this.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Can you move the documentation in to different files, leaving just the API usage XML documentation on the members, while more exhaustive documentation (with source examples) exist elsewhere. With the more exhaustive documentation being what is generated while maintaining its relationship to the class on the generated documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure who flagged this for deletion as `off-topic`, but this is completely on-topic. The Help Center states a question ca be on _software tools commonly used by programmers;_ which Doxygen falls under. There's even a tag for it. On top of that, asking how to split source-code documentation up is on-topic. If there is another reason, an explanation would be nice.

Comment: From maintenance point of view it is always better to have the documentation and definition / implementation close together. Nevertheless have you had a look at commands like \fn \class etc.?

Comment: I have not, I will look into those